# Pandas weekly schedule including holidays

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a weekly schedule/calendar to list every Friday between two dates.
If the Friday falls on a holiday, then the date shown should the previous working day (a Thursday unless that is also a holiday, in which case the Wednesday...).

I have tried a few things:

```py
import pandas as pd

local_holidays = ['2021-01-08']

my_bank_holidays = pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(
    holidays=local_holidays,
    weekmask='Fri')

reporting_date = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-31', freq=my_bank_holidays)

pd.DataFrame(reporting_date)
```

Results (below) - This skips Friday the 8th (in this example I would like to see Thursday 7th):

- 2021-01-01
- 2021-01-15
- 2021-01-22
- 2021-01-29

This next attempt doesn't include holidays:

```py
s = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-31', freq='W-FRI')

pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['Date'])
```

I have tried a monthly frequency, and that works fine for month ends - I just can't convert it to week ends:

```py
local_holidays = ['2020-01-31']

my_bank_holidays = pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd(holidays=local_holidays)

reporting_date = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-03-31', freq=my_bank_holidays)

pd.DataFrame(reporting_date)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Quick idea, not sure if it works, so posting as comment: create a frame of all Fridays. Then select all rows where Friday is a holiday. For each generate a list of all days back until the previous Friday and filter out all holidays. Assuming that they are sorted by dates just replace every holiday Friday with the last element in the list or None. Lastly, dropna to get rid of all full week holidays. Afaik, pandas should have a handy replacement function for this.

Comment: @paulgavrikov - that's not a bad idea, and I'll use that as a back up.  I was hoping I had missed some neat feature of pandas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

holidays = np.datetime64('2021-01-08')
date_range = np.arange('2021-01-01', '2021-01-31', step=7, dtype='datetime64[D]')

reporting_date = pd.DataFrame(np.busday_offset(dates=date_range, offsets=0, holidays=[holidays], roll='backward'))
print(reporting_date)
```

Output:

```
['2021-01-01' '2021-01-07' '2021-01-15' '2021-01-22' '2021-01-29']
```

Comment: Thanks - this works, but not quite what I'm after - though I could get there with this.  I'll make my question a bit clearer

Comment: The code above accepts any date range as input (e.g. Q1 = `np.arange('2021-01-01', '2021-03-31', step=7, dtype='datetime64[D]')`) - how would you represent your quarter?

Comment: For example, between two dates 1st Jan 2021 -> 31 Dec 2022, last working day of quarters Jan, Apr, July, Oct - I know pandas can figure out the last working day of the quarter, but again, same problem with the holidays.

Comment: So you are looking for the last day of each quarter in a year, shifted if it is a holiday (i.e. 31/01/2021, 30/06/2021, 30/09/20201 and 31/12/2021)?

Comment: Last working day of the quarter, that's right

Comment: That's a different question from the original request. Why would `pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd` (applied to March, June, September and December) with the holiday filter not work in this case?

Comment: You're right it is a different question, I'll stick with weeks in this question and try and figure out the quarters separately. Thanks